# Is there a way to run an expression on.exit() but only if completes normally, not on error?

Tags: r

I'm aware of the function `on.exit` in R, which is great. It runs the expression when the calling function exits, either normally or as the result of an error.

What I'd like is for the expression only to be run if the calling function returns normally, but not in the case of an error.  I have multiple points where the function could return normally, and multiple points where it could fail. Is there a way to do this?

```
myfunction = function() {
     ...
     on.exit( if (just exited normally without error) <something> )
     ...
     if (...) then return( point 1 )
     ...
     if (...) then return( point 2 )
     ...
     if (...) then return( point 3 )
     ...
     return ( point 4 )
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap the args of all your return function calls with the code that you want done. So your example becomes:

```
foo = function(thing){do something; return(thing)}
myfunction = function() {
     ...
     if (...) then return( foo(point 1) )
     ...
     if (...) then return( foo(point 2) )
     ...
     if (...) then return( foo(point 3) )
     ...
     return ( foo(point 4) )
}
```

Or just make each `then` clause into two statements. Using `on.exit` to lever some code into a number of places is going to cause spooky action-at-a-distance problems and make the baby Dijkstra cry (read Dijkstra's "GOTO considered harmful" paper).

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought of that. My `do something` is setting a flag in `.GlobalEnv` (a very unusual situation which warrants that approach, promise!). Making each `then` two statements seemed ugly due to the repetition of the same code each time, hence the `on.exit` route. But wrapping that `do something` in a function is neat!

Comment: euw! multiple exit paths, exit handlers, and now global settings! Dijkstra will be spinning in his grave!

Comment: @MatthewDowle, I know you know what you're doing, but just a heads up that [CRAN policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) says "Packages should not modify the global environment (user's workspace)."

Comment: @GSee Good point. I miswrote there, sorry. When I wrote `.GlobalEnv` I meant the `.global` in the `data.table` namespace. It's to fix [bug #2376 - If := fails the next regular print is suppressed](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2376&group_id=240&atid=975) related to FAQ 2.22 about suppressing the output of `:=`. Type `data.table:::.global$print` and it's that.

Comment: Thanks to Joris and Charles for their solutions as well but this one using the `foo()` wrapper is the one now used by `data.table` to fix [bug #2376](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2376&group_id=240&atid=975), hence accepted this one. Thanks Spacedman!

Answer (score 15):

The whole point of `on.exit()` is exactly to be run regardless of the exit status. Hence it disregards any error signal. This is afaik equivalent to the `finally` statement of the tryCatch function.

If you want to run code only on normal exit, simply put it at the end of your code. Yes, you'll have to restructure it a bit using `else` statements and by creating only 1 exit point, but that's considered good coding practice by some.

Using your example, that would be:

```
myfunction = function() {
     ...
     if (...) then out <- point 1 
     ...
     else if (...) then out <- point 2 
     ...
     else if (...) then out <- point 3 
     ...
     else out <-  point 4 

     WhateverNeedsToRunBeforeReturning

     return(out)
}
```

Or see the [answer of Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607376/428790) for a nice implementation of this idea using `local()`.

If you insist on using `on.exit()`, you can gamble on the working of the traceback mechanism to do something like this :

```
test <- function(x){
  x + 12
}                               

myFun <- function(y){
    on.exit({

        err <- if( exists(".Traceback")){
           nt <- length(.Traceback)        
           .Traceback[[nt]] == sys.calls()[[1]]
        } else {FALSE}

        if(!err) print("test")
    })  
    test(y)
}
```

`.Traceback` contains the last call stack resulting in an error. You have to check whether the top call in that stack is equal to the current call, and in that case your call very likely threw the last error. So based on that condition you can try to hack yourself a solution I'd never use myself.

Comment: +1 Many thanks. I know what you mean and fully agree. But in the particular situation I have, restructuring the code will be difficult. I was hoping for a way to do the `if (just exited normally without error)` part; e.g., is there a `last.error` or something, similar to `.Last.value`?

Comment: @MatthewDowle There is, and it's obtained by `geterrmessage()`. But if you ran code that gave an error before running your function, `geterrmessage()` will return that error. That's why you have to check the call stack using `sys.calls()` and the `.Traceback` as in my second example. It does the `if(just exited normally)` you ask for. I just don't know how stable that solution is, so I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Can you just move the code into a nested function (thus keeping the returns), and have the outer function clean up - ie `f = function() { g = function() { ... }; ret = g(); cleanup(); ret }`

Comment: @Charles That is exactly what I do in my last example. You need to catch the error as well. Plus, if the cleanup depends on objects made in the inner function, that solution won't work as those objects aren't available any more.

Comment: Not sure why you need to catch the error? I thought the whole point was that the cleanup is only to be run unless there's an error, in which case it's fine to let the exception bubble up. Good point about possible needing access to certain variables though - I'd do all that in the outer function.

Comment: Also come to think of it, using `local({})` instead of creating and then calling a function would look a bit cleaner - eg `f = function() { myvar = 1; local({ some code that may error }); my code to run on success }`. `return` will return from the local scope, not the function. As an added bonus - passing `environment()` as the second arg to `local` also runs the nested code in the parent scope, so no issues with inaccessible variables in the outer scope.

Comment: @Charles Linked to your answer and removed the tryCatch ballast. OP indeed didn't ask for it

Answer (score 6):

Bit more readable version of my comment on @Joris' answer:

```
f = function() {
  ret = local({
    myvar = 42
    if (runif(1) < 0.5)
      return(2)
    stop('oh noes')
  }, environment())
  # code to run on success...
  print(sprintf('myvar is %d', myvar))
  ret
}
```

Comment: +1  it is essentially another (nice) way of doing what I stated first : run the code you want to run at the end of your function. Also, just explain what you do, so people don't have to dig in the load of comments under my answer.

Comment: +1 too. I could just wrap my existing function body with that local as you've showed, then. Didn't think of that either. Thanks! Will experiment ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is not a clean way yet. I usually create an OK variable at the beginning as FALSE and turn it to TRUE at the end. I prefer `on.exit` over isolating all my code into a `tryCatch`.

```
myfun = function() {
  
 OK=F # the flag "OK" will be FALSE until the function ends OK  

 conn = my.db.connection.function()
 dbBegin(conn)
 
 on.exit({
   if(OK) dbCommit(conn) else dbRollback(conn)
   dbDisconnect(conn)
 })

 # ... Your code. You can edit database as a transaction. 
 # if anything fails in R or in the database a rollback will occur
 
 OK=T # only if the code came to the end everything went ok, so we set the flag OK as TRUE

 return(NULL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no legitimate reason your function would return `NULL`, you can check the return value from within `on.exit`.

So to execute an expression only on normal exit:

```
myFunction <- function(){
  
  on.exit(if(!is.null(returnValue())) message("All systems normal"))
  
  ...<rest of function>...

}
```