# knitr gets tricked by data.table `:=` assignment

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

It seems that `knitr` doesn't understand that `DT[, a:=1]` should not result in an output of `DT` to the document.  Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

### Example `knitr` document:

````
Data.Table Markdown
========================================================
Suppose we make a `data.table` in **R Markdown**
```{r}
DT = data.table(a = rnorm(10))
```
Notice that it doesn't display the contents until we do a
```{r}
DT
```
style command.  However, if we want to use `:=` to create another column
```{r}
DT[, c:=5]
```
It would appear that the absence of a equals sign tricks `knitr` into thinking this 
is to be printed.
````

### Knitr Output:

[image]

Is this a `knitr` bug or a `data.table` bug?

**EDIT**

I have only just noticed, that `knitr` is being weird when it is `echo`ing the code.  Look at the output above.  In my source code I have `DT[, c:=5]` but what `knitr` renders is

```
DT[, `:=`(c, 5)]
```

Weird...

**EDIT 2: Caching**

Caching also seems to have a problem with `:=` but that must be a different cause, so is a separate question here: [why does knitr caching fail for data.table `:=`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298359/1900520)

Comment: I find it hard to follow as to how this is a `data.table` bug. what happens if you assign it back to DT? (although I'm not sure if MatthewDowle would like it).

Comment: Good thought!  `DT=DT[, :=]` is a viable workaround.  I suspect it must be `knitr` but I don't know how `knitr` decides if it should output or not - is it purely the presence of assignment?  `data.table` has clearly done something to stop output in the console - perhaps this is not comprehensive enough?

Comment: If you wrap the expression in invisible() then knitr doesn't print it, which makes me think knitr is being cleverer than just not printing if there's an assignment. But then I think maybe data.table should return an invisible object in this case, hence a bug in data.table might be a possibility. Why doesn't it get printed anyway? That has to be data.table's business...

Comment: @Spacedman, for a `:=` (assign by reference), yes it doesn't. You'll have to either use `print(DT[, LHS := RHS])` or `DT[, LHS := RHS][]`.

Comment: @Corone, now I see the point as to why you think there might be something with `data.table`.

Comment: If I get the latest data.table from R-forge and load it with devtools I do see printed output with `DT[,c:=1]`. But only when loaded with devtools. The package does have some crufty-looking mucking with `invisible()` here and there and a `.global` object. Hmmm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update Oct 2014**.  Now in data.table v1.9.5 :

> `:=` no longer prints in `knitr` for consistency with behaviour at the prompt, [#505](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/505). Output of a test `knit("knitr.Rmd")` is now in data.table's unit tests.

and related :

> `if (TRUE) DT[,LHS:=RHS]` now doesn't print (thanks to Jureiss, [#869](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/869)). Test added. To get this to work we've had to live with one downside: if a `:=` is used inside a function with no `DT[]` before the end of the function, then the next time `DT` is typed at the prompt, nothing will be printed. A repeated `DT` will print. To avoid this: include a `DT[]` after the last `:=` in your function. If that is not possible (e.g., it's not a function you can change) then `print(DT)` and `DT[]` at the prompt are guaranteed to print. As before, adding an extra `[]` on the end of a `:=` query is a recommended idiom to update and then print; e.g. `> DT[,foo:=3L][]`

---

---

Previous answer kept for posterity  (the `global$depthtrigger` business is no longer done as from data.table v1.9.5 so this is no longer true) ...

Just to be clear I understand then: `knitr` is printing when you don't want it to.

Try increasing `data.table:::.global$depthtrigger` a little bit at the start of the script.

This will be 3 for you currently :

```
data.table:::.global$depthtrigger
[1] 3
```

I don't know how much eval depth `knitr` adds to the stack. But try changing the trigger to 4 first; i.e.

```
assign("depthtrigger", 4, data.table:::.global)
```

and at the end of the `knitr` script ensure to set it back to 3. If 4 doesn't work, try 5, then 6.  If you get to 10 give up and I'll think again.  ;-P

Why might this work?

See NEWS from v1.8.4 :

> `DT[,LHS:=RHS,...]` no longer prints `DT`. This implements #2128 "Try
>   again to get `DT[i,j:=value]` to return invisibly". Thanks to discussions here :
>   [how to suppress output when using `:=` in R {data.table}, prior to v1.8.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359553/how-to-suppress-output-when-using-in-r-data-table) 
>   http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Avoiding-print-when-using-tp4643076.html 
>           FAQs 2.21 and 2.22 have been updated.
>
> *FAQ 2.21 Why does DT[i,col:=value] return the whole of DT? I expected either no visible value (consistent with <-), or a message or return
>   value containing how many rows were updated. It isn't obvious that the
>   data has indeed been updated by reference.* 
>  This has changed in v1.8.3
>   to meet your expectations. Please upgrade. The whole of DT is returned
>   (now invisibly) so that compound syntax can work; e.g.,
>   DT[i,done:=TRUE][,sum(done)]. The number of rows updated is returned
>   when verbosity is on, either on a per query basis or globally using
>   options(datatable.verbose=TRUE).
>
> *FAQ 2.22 Ok, thanks. What was so difficult about the result of DT[i,col:=value] being returned invisibly?* 
>  R internally forces
>   visibility on for [. The value of FunTab's eval column (see
>   src/main/names.c) for [ is 0 meaning force R_Visible on (see
>   R-Internals section 1.6). Therefore, when we tried invisible() or
>   setting R_Visible to 0 directly ourselves, eval in src/main/eval.c
>   would force it on again. To solve this problem, the key was to stop
>   trying to stop the print method running after a :=. Instead, inside :=
>   we now (from v1.8.3) set a global flag which the print method uses to
>   know whether to actually print or not.

That global flag is `data.table:::.global$print`.  At the top of `data.table:::print.data.table` you'll see it looking at it. That's because there is no known way to suppress printing from `[` (as FAQ 2.22 explains).

So, inside `:=` inside `[.data.table` it looks to see how "deep" this call is :

```
if (Cstack_info()[["eval_depth"]] <= .global$depthtrigger) {
    suppPrint = function(x) { .global$print=FALSE; x }
    # Suppress print when returns ok not on error, bug #2376.
    # Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606880/403310
    # All appropriate returns following this point are
    # wrapped i.e. return(suppPrint(x)).
}
```

Essential that's just saying:  if `DT[,x:=y]` is running at the prompt, then I know the REPL is going to call the `print` method on my result, beyond my control.  Ok, so given `print` method is going to run, I'm going to suppress it inside that `print` method by setting a flag (since the `print` method that runs (i.e. `print.data.table`) is something I can control).

In `knitr`'s case it's simulating the REPL in a clever way. It isn't really a script, iiuc, otherwise `DT[,x:=y]` wouldn't print anyway for that reason.  But because it's simulating REPL via an `eval` there is an extra level of `eval` depth for code run from `knitr`. Or something similar (I don't know `knitr`).

Which is why I'm thinking increasing the `depthtrigger` might do the trick.

Hacky/crufty, I agree. But if it works, and you let me know which value works, I can change `data.table` to be `knitr` aware and change the `depthtrigger` automatically.  Or any better solutions are most welcome.

Comment: aargh! I just spent half an hour digging that out of the source code! Why is testing against C stack depth a good test for whether to invisibilise the result?

Comment: @Spacedman It's probably not _good_ per se. But it was the only way I found so far to know whether the result returned by this call to `[.data.table` is about to printed by the REPL.  The internals of `invisible()` also set a global flag, btw.  Basically, R ignores the invisibility of `[.class`'s result and prints it anyway (FAQ 2.22).

Comment: Just done this, and it works with the caveat that `depthtrigger = 53` is the smallest number that prevents printing!

Comment: @Carone Crikey. Anybody know why `knitr` might add so many levels to the stack?

Comment: Is `knitr` byte compiled?  If not, that might explain it.

Comment: Because when developing `data.table` (I just source() .R code into .GlobalEnv, essentially) I need `depthtrigger` to be 9. But when the package is installed, `depthtrigger` can be the much lower 3. I assume that's something to do with DESCRIPTION containing `ByteCompile: TRUE`.

Comment: Why do you care whether `DT[,x:=y]` is running at the prompt? Why not just always set your magic invisibility flag in these cases? Then if it is at the prompt, it's silent, and if it isn't, nothing bad happens anyway.

Comment: @Spacedman Because something bad does happen. If the flag is set, and the print method doesn't run, fine. But then the flag is still set. The _next_ thing the user types might be merely `DT`. That would then not print, and be confusing. Typing `DT` again a second time would then really print it.  So I need to be careful to only set the  flag when I know the REPL is going to call the print method on the result. If not I must not set the flag.

Comment: Ugh. Really the only decent thing to do is not to subvert the idea that assignment is the only way of changing an object in R :)

Comment: @Spacedman Sometimes you gotta break some eggs to make an omlette, even if a few bits of shell do fall in.

Comment: Update introduced in v1.9.5 , does not seem to work in v1.9.6 anymore (or 1.9.7 as of today). knitr still prints data.table after := assignment.

Comment: @JavK Thanks for reporting.  It is tested though and that test is passing.  Can  you create a reproducible example?  Perhaps it's different to the existing test.  The news item in v1.9.6 was ":= no longer prints in knitr for consistency with behaviour at the prompt, #505. Output of a test knit("knitr.Rmd") is now in data.table's unit tests. Thanks to Corone for the illustrated report."

Comment: @MattDowle I get the same as JavK. See here: http://rpubs.com/ac_evu/230003 and http://pastebin.com/raw/rb37eXZS

Comment: @MattDowle sorry for a very late reply. Please see here: http://rpubs.com/Keell/230348

Comment: @JavaK Thanks. Here's the passing test in data.table. As far as I can see it covers yours.  What's the difference? Your example does not seem to be reproducible in the sense that I can run it with `R --vanilla`. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/tests/knitr.Rmd

Comment: @JavaK And here is the .save output that `R CMD check` compares to :  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/tests/knitr.Rout.save

Comment: Linking to [issue #1930](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1930), thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use:

````
```{r, results='hide'}
DT[, c:=5]
```
````

Comment: Because it is likely not the only thing in the block. As work arounds go, self assignment is probably better. Finally what if your assignment calls a function (inplace of '5') which prints.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone returning to this in 2017 with RMarkdown 1.3 and data.table 1.10 or similar, there was a [resurgence of this bug, as identified and documented here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1930)

This was subsequently fixed in RMarkdown 1.4

Answer (score 2):

Just surround the expression with invisible(). This works for me.

Comment: This is not ideal because if `echo = TRUE` and the output is to be used as a tutorial/reference, new learners might be led to believe it's normal/required to use `invisible` in regular coding (it's not). Unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across the same problem and I solved it fairly easy by re-assigning the variable. In your case:

```
DT <- DT[, ':=' (c, 5)]
```

It's a bit more verbose though, especially if the variable name is big.

Comment: this is the smiplest method I've found. Especially if you don't want to update to the dev version (as the current cran seems to be v1.9.4)