# Extend data.table class with custom print method

Tags: r, data.table

### Question

How do I suppress `:=` from printing to the console after extending `data.table` into a new class and writing a custom print method?

### Example

In this example I'm extending `data.table` by adding `extended.data.table` to the class.

I'm also adding an attribute to one of the columns that I want to print in a specific format.

```
library(data.table)
## create data.table
dt_extend <- data.table(id = 1:5,
                        val = letters[1:5])

## create two attributes:
## - extend.data.table  onto data.table
## - extended           onto the 'val' column
setattr(dt_extend, 'class', c('extended.data.table', class(dt_extend)))
setattr(dt_extend[['val']], 'extended', 'print')

## Method to format the 'extended' column when printed
print.extended.data.table <- function(edt){

    ## find the 'extended' column
    cols <- sapply(edt, function(x) names(attributes(x)))
    cols <- names(which(cols == "extended"))

    ## more than one column can have the 'extended' attribute
    edt <- edt[,  
            lapply(.SD, function(y) { paste0("formatted: ", y) } ), 
            by = setdiff(names(edt), cols), 
            .SDcols = cols
            ]

    ## now call data.table print
    NextMethod()
}

## these all print as expected
dt_extend
dt_extend[1, .(val)]

str(dt_extend)
# Classes ‘extended.data.table’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ id : int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ val: atomic  a b c d ...
# ..- attr(*, "extended")= chr "print"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Updating by-reference using `:=` correctly updates the column, but it also prints to the console.

Why does this happen, and/or how do I stop it printing?

```
## why does this update AND print?
dt_extend[, val2 := val]
```

---

Looks like these are all related and the issues I'm describing:

- https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-thanks.-what-was-so-difficult-about-the-result-of-dti-col-value-being-returned-invisibly
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/933
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L36

---

### Update

There is a line inside [`print.data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L54) that says

> `if (nrows <= 0L) return(invisible())   # ability to turn off printing`

Where `nrows` is defined in the function arguments as

```
nrows=getOption("datatable.print.nrows")
```

Which is an `option`, that can be set by

```
options("datatable.print.nrows" = -1L)
```

setting this option does indeed suppress the print when using `:=`. Maybe I can be clever with this and override the given `"datatable.print.nrows"` option if the user has used `:=`?

Comment: Might be related. I was trying to do the opposite. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626814/822162

Comment: Thanks @ClaytonStanley, I'll have a look into it, but I'm hoping there's a way of doing it without modifying / accessing different environments

Answer (score 3):

to stop printing you can do `invisible(dt_extend[, val2 := val])`
you can check this maybe https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1122

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm after a solution that allows me to keep the intended functionality of `:=`, rather than having to call `invisible()` (as ultimately this will be going in a package of my own)

Comment: @SymbolixAU what is wrong about `invisible` if you have to write own `print` method anyway? just use it there.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I would go with PR to data.table so you won't need to maintain own "extended.data.table" class.

Comment: @jangorecki - I've just found [this FR 1091](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1091), which implements what I'm after, so I think i'm sorted.