# R Notebook and R Markdown documents "tricked" by data.table `:=` assignment?

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown, rnotebook

The title of this question refers back to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267018/knitr-gets-tricked-by-data-table-assignment?noredirect=1&lq=1) that was answered a couple of years ago. 
The issue raised and resolved there with data.table and knitr seems to have reappeared with the relatively new R Notebooks from RStudio and R Markdown.

In brief, as covered in data.table FAQ 2.21 and 2.22 a data.table should not print when using :=, the assignment by reference operator. The print behavior was a past issue with R and knitr that the data.table folks appear to have spent a lot of effort fixing (for instance, see [their GitHub Issue #505](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/505)). But now it's happening again with R Notebooks, both in interactive mode and using Knit to HTML.

The [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267018/knitr-gets-tricked-by-data-table-assignment?noredirect=1&lq=1) pretty much covers the  minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the behavior. Put simply, this statement will print when running it from a R Notebook or R Markdown document:

```
DT[, x := sum(y)]
```

It does not print when run from the Console or a standard R Script file.

I'm using the most recent version of data.table available through CRAN, v1.10.0, and RStudio v1.0.44.

Some workarounds noted in the previous question, such as using <- or wrapping the operations with invisible(), do work with the R Notebooks. They're not overly burdensome to use, yet as also noted in that previous question, they're not ideal fixes.

I'm a grateful user of this amazing software but am still fairly unsophisticated on the inner workings. If I'm missing something obvious or a duplicate question somewhere, my apologies. And perhaps I should be posting this issue with RStudio instead of here. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knitr gets tricked by data.table \`:=\` assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267018/knitr-gets-tricked-by-data-table-assignment)

Comment: The OP specifically refers to that post to point out that a previously fixed problem has recurred.

Comment: Report it to the data.table devs on github.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1930